# Aluminum rivet used to join stainless steel and aluminum sheet

Tags: structures, joining, rivets

I am using Aluminum pop rivets to join stainless steel and aluminum sheet together. I am aware of the galvanic corrosion risk in this situation. Are there any other risks the joint may face over time due to material mechanical properties differences ( Aluminum - soft and stainless steel - Hard )?

Comment: Galvanic corrosion requires an electrolyte, most commonly water.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the rivet's toughness and the thickness of the sheets.

Either the stainless steel will cut the rivet, or the rivet will cut a slot in the aluminium.

The use of rivet or any other fastner on  the sheet work is optimal only when the alasticity of the two sides being joined is equal at the joint. That's why the revets are lined up at equal spaces as much as possible.